# What camera & lens combinations are ideal for animal photography

Tags: flash

What camera & lens combinations are ideal for animal photography?

I tried to do it with my Canon camera.

Comment: Hi Daniel. I see a couple of problems with this question... the biggest is that it's too broad, there are a lot of possible answers to it because it's not only camera/lens options, it also includes preferred subjects. Secondly, it has a strong potential to be opinion based, rather than entirely factual, and is going to result in answers with a brand bias that can lead to debate.

Comment: Please provide some more information about the type of animals, distances, environments etc. and it should be easier to answer.

Answer (score 1):

A Canon or other brands of DSLR will be needed, and the specs depend on your goals for shooting.
You must prioritize a long lens and possibly a tele extender or two to get started.  A good strong tripod and a gimbal head to support your big lens.  The exact size of the lens you need depends on the size and distance of your animals.  Shoot smaller animals ant you may be able to get closer than larger animals, like lions, tigers or bears (oh my) You may wish for the longest lenses.

Canon has great 600mm and 400 mm lenses.  All great things do come at a price and their costs are equally great. Somewhere north of 11k for the 600mm lens.  But if price is no object, get yourself a 1dX and that 600mm beast and you will be able to shoot the big game.

The other platforms have somewhat equal bodies and lenses as well, so I suggest renting the kit of your dreams and shoot up your local wilderness and see what you think. That will allow you to try each one before you plunk down all your hard earned money, and get a feel for which systems and lenses you prefer for the particular animals your hunting.

Comment: I have to admit that suggesting somebody asking such a basic question consider buying equipment costing north of $18,000 seems to be suspect advice. If he's that new to the game, you might want to start him off a little less costly...

Comment: Agreed that this is really overkill.  It is certainly the way to get the best possible results for an experienced photographer, but it is overkill and actually even potentially counter productive to someone just starting out.